# polymer отправка формы на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, компоненты, polymer

есть [starter-kit](https://github.com/Polymer/shop) для интернет магазина, не пойму как на полимере сделать отправку форму ajax'ом все перепробовал.

вот как работает на чистом html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //E-mail Ajax Send
        $("form").submit(function() { //Change
            var th = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mail.php", //Change
                data: th.serialize()
            }).done(function() {
                alert("Спасибо, заявку приняли!",th);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Done Functions
                    th.trigger("reset");
                }, 1000);
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
```

это php скрипт:

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

как тоже самое с полимером сделать не могу разобраться, пробовал iron-ajx - https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax не могу отправить данные с формы -- заполненый емай, на скипт php и обработать его.

вот форма и обработчик в полимере - метод `_submit`.

```js
<dom-module id="shop-checkout">

  <template>

    <div class="main-frame">
      <iron-pages id="pages" selected="[[state]]" attr-for-selected="state">
        <div state="init">
          <iron-form id="checkoutForm"
              on-iron-form-response="_didReceiveResponse"
              on-iron-form-presubmit="_willSendRequest">
            <form method="post" action="data/sample_success_response.json">

              <div class="subsection" visible$="[[!_hasItems]]">
                <p class="empty-cart">Your <iron-icon icon="shopping-cart"></iron-icon> is empty.</p>
              </div>

              <header class="subsection" visible$="[[_hasItems]]">
                <h1>Checkout</h1>
                <span>Shop is a demo app - form data will not be sent</span>
              </header>

              <div class="subsection grid" visible$="[[_hasItems]]">
                <section>
                  <h2 id="accountInfoHeading">Account Information</h2>
                  <div class="row input-row">
                    <shop-input>
                      <input type="email" id="accountEmail" name="accountEmail"
                          placeholder="Email" autofocus required
                          aria-labelledby="accountEmailLabel accountInfoHeading">
                      <shop-md-decorator error-message="Invalid Email" aria-hidden="true">
                        <label id="accountEmailLabel">Email</label>
                        <shop-underline></shop-underline>
                      </shop-md-decorator>
                    </shop-input>
                  </div>
         
                  <shop-button responsive id="submitBox">
                    <input type="button" on-click="_submit" value="Place Order">
                  </shop-button>

              </div>
            </form>
          </iron-form>
        </div>

        <!-- Success message UI -->
        <header state="success">
          <h1>Thank you</h1>
          <p>[[response.successMessage]]</p>
          <shop-button responsive>
            <a href="/">Finish</a>
          </shop-button>
        </header>

        <!-- Error message UI -->
        <header state="error">
          <h1>We couldn&acute;t process your order</h1>
          <p id="errorMessage">[[response.errorMessage]]</p>
          <shop-button responsive>
            <a href="/checkout">Try again</a>
          </shop-button>
        </header>

      </iron-pages>

    </div>

    <!-- Handles the routing for the success and error subroutes -->
    <app-route
        active="{{routeActive}}"
        data="{{routeData}}"
        route="[[route]]"
        pattern="/:state">
     </app-route>

    <!-- Show spinner when waiting for the server to repond -->
    <paper-spinner-lite active="[[waiting]]"></paper-spinner-lite>

  </template>

  <script>

    class ShopCheckout extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() { return 'shop-checkout'; }

      static get properties() { return {

        /**
         * The route for the state. e.g. `success` and `error` are mounted in the
         * `checkout/` route.
         */
        route: {
          type: Object,
          notify: true
        },

        /**
         * The total price of the contents in the user's cart.
         */
        total: Number,

        /**
         * The state of the form. Valid values are:
         * `init`, `success` and `error`.
         */
        state: {
          type: String,
          value: 'init'
        },

        /**
         * An array containing the items in the cart.
         */
        cart: Array,

        /**
         * The server's response.
         */
        response: Object,

        /**
         * If true, the user must enter a billing address.
         */
        hasBillingAddress: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false
        },

        /**
         * If true, shop-checkout is currently visible on the screen.
         */
        visible: {
          type: Boolean,
          observer: '_visibleChanged'
        },

        /**
         * True when waiting for the server to repond.
         */
        waiting: {
          type: Boolean,
          readOnly: true,
          reflectToAttribute: true
        },

        /**
         * True when waiting for the server to repond.
         */
        _hasItems: {
          type: Boolean,
          computed: '_computeHasItem(cart.length)'
        }

      }}

      static get observers() { return [
        '_updateState(routeActive, routeData)'
      ]}

      _submit(e) {
        if (this._validateForm()) {
          // To send the form data to the server:
          // 2) Remove the code below.
          // 3) Uncomment `this.$.checkoutForm.submit()`.

          this.$.checkoutForm.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('iron-form-presubmit', {
            composed: true}));

          this._submitFormDebouncer = Polymer.Debouncer.debounce(this._submitFormDebouncer,
            Polymer.Async.timeOut.after(1000), () => {
              this.$.checkoutForm.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('iron-form-response', {
                composed: true, detail: {
                  response: {
                    success: 1,
                    successMessage: 'Demo checkout process complete.'
                  }
                }}));
            });

          // this.$.checkoutForm.submit();
        }
      }

      /**
       * Sets the valid state and updates the location.
       */
      _pushState(state) {
        this._validState = state;
        this.set('route.path', state);
      }

      /**
       * Checks that the `:state` subroute is correct. That is, the state has been pushed
       * after receiving response from the server. e.g. Users can only go to `/checkout/success`
       * if the server responsed with a success message.
       */
      _updateState(active, routeData) {
        if (active && routeData) {
          let state = routeData.state;
          if (this._validState === state) {
            this.state = state;
            this._validState = '';
            return;
          }
        }
        this.state = 'init';
      }

      /**
       * Sets the initial state.
       */
      _reset() {
        let form = this.$.checkoutForm;

        this._setWaiting(false);
        form.reset();

        let nativeForm = form._form;
        if (!nativeForm) {
          return;
        }

        // Remove the `aria-invalid` attribute from the form inputs.
        for (let el, i = 0; el = nativeForm.elements[i], i < nativeForm.elements.length; i++) {
          el.removeAttribute('aria-invalid');
        }
      }

      /**
       * Validates the form's inputs and adds the `aria-invalid` attribute to the inputs
       * that don't match the pattern specified in the markup.
       */
      _validateForm() {
        let form = this.$.checkoutForm;
        let firstInvalid = false;
        let nativeForm = form._form;

        for (let el, i = 0; el = nativeForm.elements[i], i < nativeForm.elements.length; i++) {
          if (el.checkValidity()) {
            el.removeAttribute('aria-invalid');
          } else {
            if (!firstInvalid) {
              // announce error message
              if (el.nextElementSibling) {
                this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('announce', {bubbles: true, composed: true,
                  detail: el.nextElementSibling.getAttribute('error-message')}));
              }
              if (el.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded) {
                // safari, chrome
                el.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
              } else {
                // firefox, edge, ie
                el.scrollIntoView(false);
              }
              el.focus();
              firstInvalid = true;
            }
            el.setAttribute('aria-invalid', 'true');
          }
        }
        return !firstInvalid;
      }

      /**
       * Adds the cart data to the payload that will be sent to the server
       * and updates the UI to reflect the waiting state.
       */
      _willSendRequest(e) {
        let form = e.target;
        let body = form.ajax && form.ajax.body;

        this._setWaiting(true);

        if (!body) {
          return;
        }
        // Populate the request body where `cartItemsId[i]` is the ID and `cartItemsQuantity[i]`
        // is the quantity for some item `i`.
        body.cartItemsId = [];
        body.cartItemsQuantity = [];

        this.cart.forEach((cartItem) => {
          body.cartItemsId.push(cartItem.item.name);
          body.cartItemsQuantity.push(cartItem.quantity);
        });
      }

      /**
       * Handles the response from the server by checking the response status
       * and transitioning to the success or error UI.
       */
      _didReceiveResponse(e) {
        let response = e.detail.response;

        this.response = response;
        this._setWaiting(true);

        if (response.success) {
          this._pushState('success');
          this._reset();
          this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('clear-cart', {bubbles: true, composed: true}));
        } else {
          this._pushState('error');
        }
      }

      _toggleBillingAddress(e) {
        this.hasBillingAddress = e.target.checked;

        if (this.hasBillingAddress) {
          this.$.billAddress.focus();
        }
      }

      _computeHasItem(cartLength) {
        return cartLength > 0;
      }

      _formatPrice(total) {
        return isNaN(total) ? '' : '$' + total.toFixed(2);
      }

      _getEntryTotal(entry) {
        return this._formatPrice(entry.quantity * entry.item.price);
      }

      _visibleChanged(visible) {
        if (!visible) {
          return;
        }
        // Reset the UI states
        this._reset();
        // Notify the page's title
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change-section', {
          bubbles: true, composed: true, detail: { title: 'Checkout' }}));
      }

    }

    customElements.define(ShopCheckout.is, ShopCheckout);

  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2):

Допустим, есть компонент и у него внутри есть форма:

```
<dom-module ...>
<style>
</style>
<template>
<form id="someForm">
  ...
  <button type=submit on-click="Submit"></button>
</form>
</template>
</dom-module>

<script>
 class ... 
 get is{...
 }
Submit(){
let form=this.$.someForm; // объект формы теперь в переменной form. Можете брать из него данные и отправлять запрос
}
</script>
```

Вариант 2: если делать отдельный компонент с формой:

```
<form id="someForm">
  <input value="{{Name}}"></input>
  <input email="{{Email}}"></input>
  ...
</form>
<script>
 class ... 
 static get properties(){
                return {
                    Name:{
                        type: String
                        value:"",                       
                    },
                    Email:{
                        type: String,
                        value:"",
                    },
              /*Еще свойства */
    }
    Send(){
      let data={
    Name:this.Name,
    Email:this.Email
    ...
    }
        /*отправка данных,например через XMLHttpRequest или fetch*/
    }

connectedCallback(){
this.$.someForm.submit=this.Send;
}

</script>
```